# Why am I having a problem downloading patent data with "patentsview" in R

Tags: r, patentsview

I am trying to fetch patent data with the "patentsview" package in R but I am always getting an error and I couldn't find the solution anywhere. Here's my code -

```
# Load library
library(patentsview)

# Write query
query <- with_qfuns(
  and(
    begins(cpc_subgroup_id = 'G06N'),
    gte(patent_year = 2020)
  )
)

# Create a list of fields
# get_fields(endpoint = "patents")

# Needed Fields
fields <- c(
  "patent_id",
  "patent_title",
  "patent_abstract",
  "patent_date"
)

# Send an HTTP request to the PatentsView API to get the data
pv_res <- search_pv(query = query, fields = fields, all_pages = TRUE)
```

The output is -

```
Error in xheader_er_or_status(resp) : Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

What am I doing wrong here? And what is the solution?

Comment: Maybe you're better off raising an issue with the developers of the package here: https://github.com/ropensci/patentsview

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorGustafsson. I'll do that. But do you have any idea about this error?

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the query since you're getting a 404 (indicating what you're trying to fetch from the server doesn't exist). But I can't really help you with fixing it since I'm not familiar with the package, sorry.

Comment: Hey @NoobProgrammer, I'm the developer of patentsview. Try downloading the development edition of the package. That should solve your issue. See here for how to do that: https://github.com/ropensci/patentsview